# No OS installed message for specific ROMs

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms

I'm having troubles with installing ROMs. I've been using a custom ROM (crdroid) on my Redmi 5 plus device for quite some time. I have recently decided to give another custom ROMs a try and downloaded [Resurrection Remix](https://get.resurrectionremix.com/ten/vince/RROS-Q-8.5.7-20200813-vince-Official.zip) and [Evolution X](https://sourceforge.net/projects/evolution-x/files/vince/EvolutionX_4.5_vince-10.0-20200714-0943-OFFICIAL.zip/download). But I can't install them as after flashing, TWRP is saying there is no OS to boot from. But when I flash [CrDroid](https://sourceforge.net/projects/crdroid/files/vince/6.x/crDroidAndroid-10.0-20200826-vince-v6.9.zip/download) back, it is booting perfectly fine. Here's how I am flashing ROMs:

First I'm wiping Dalvik & Cache, cache, system and data. Then I'm just flashing the ROM's zip. The strange thing is that it is working for CrDroid. I even tried wiping internal storage and formatting data but still no luck. Right now I'm posting this from CrDroid as I put it back.

Comment: This might be a weird question, but ensure that you're flashing the custom ROM specifically built for Redmi 5, not for other devices? (consider mentioning the DL link to the Resurrection Remix and Evolution X?)

Comment: @AndrewT. I added the links